# Sumar dos en una piramide de numeros en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una piramide de numeros en javascript de la siguiente forma:

```
  var numrep = prompt("Introduce numero de repeticiones");

      for (i = 0; i <=numrep; i++) {
          for (rep = 1; rep <= i; rep++) {
              document.write(rep);
          }
          document.write("<br>");
      }
```

La cual muestra, depende del numero que le pasemos (5):

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5...
```

Pero mi objetivo es lograr esta forma:

```
1
3 1
5 3 1
7 5 3 1
9 7 5 3 1...
```

Sé que se tienen que sumar dos a cada nuevo dígito que se muestre, pero no logro comprender la mecánica. Cómo puedo hacer para que se sumen dos cada vez que se muestre??

Comment: para el segundo caso, yo cambiaria el primer bucle, iniciandolo a 1, y que el incremental fuera `i=i+2`. con eso tendrias el primer valor de 1, 3, 5, 7, 9... la siguiente parte te la dejo para ti.  (Nota: al cambiar el bucle inicial la condicion debe cambiar...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las filas dependen del primer `for`, las columnas/celdas del segundo `for` para tener el resultado "invertido" puedes empezar por el final y recorrer hacia atrás el segundo `for`. La "distancia" que esperas entre los números es de 2, osea que son mútiplos de 2, solo que corridos 1. Es decir `* 2 + 1`

```js
var numrep = prompt("Introduce numero de repeticiones");

for (i = 1; i <= numrep; i++) {

  for (rep = i - 1; rep >= 0; rep--) {
    document.write((rep * 2 + 1) + ' ');
  }
  document.write("<br>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución posible ocultando los multiplos de dos:

```
  for (i = 1; i<=numrep; i=i+2) {
      for (x = i; x >= 1; x--) {
        if (x%2!==0) {
          document.write(x);
        }
      }
      document.write("<br>");
  }
```